# Why do Office 16.x installs create "Microsoft Office 15" and "Office15" folders in $PROGRAMFILES and its subfolders?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

My laptop has Microsoft 365, and has never had Office 2013 installed on it. But it does have a `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15` directory as well as the expected `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office`.

The Office 15 directory contains just one subdirectory, `ClientX64`, which in turn contains two `.exe` files. Using Git Bash to run the `md5sum` utility, we can see that the two .exe files are identical:

```
$ ls -la
total 10464
drwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096       0 Jul 27  2021 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096       0 Jul 27  2021 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096 5353512 Jan  5 17:30 IntegratedOffice.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096 5353512 Jan  5 17:30 OfficeClickToRun.exe*

AUTH+McJa254@HP-CND21307HX MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Microsoft Office 15/ClientX64
$ md5sum IntegratedOffice.exe
bae7ef9f67a3494eab92c9e82f7af177 *IntegratedOffice.exe

AUTH+McJa254@HP-CND21307HX MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Microsoft Office 15/ClientX64
$ md5sum OfficeClickToRun.exe
bae7ef9f67a3494eab92c9e82f7af177 *OfficeClickToRun.exe
```

There is also an "Office15" subfolder of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root`, alongside the expected "Office16". It contains a DLL file and an XRM-MS file:

```
$ cd "/c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office15"

$ ls -la
total 2072
drwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096       0 Aug  8 12:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096       0 Aug  8 12:01 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096 1477512 Aug  8 11:56 pidgenx.dll*
-rw-r--r-- 1 AUTH+McJa254 4096  635419 Jul 27  2021 pkeyconfig-office.xrm-ms
```

Does anyone know why Office 16.x is installing folders that would seem to be specific to a 15.0 (Office 2013) install, especially as these don't appear to contain much that could be related to backwards compatibility (although maybe the .exe files are intended to install something of that sort?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal Office install on new machines.  I see that here on 3 new(ish) machines that have only ever had Office 365 install.

Microsoft may have done this for some (obscure) compatibility requirement (I am not certain).

You can safely just ignore the folder. It is quite small and does not cause any issue of any kind.

Comment: Pretty sure, the reason is that the installer (click to run) which has things like scheduled tasks etc, is kept the same so that doesn't break. With scheduled tasks, you don't want to have to keep changing the path etc.